# Transfering to a new S.D card

Tags: pi-3, kernel

I recently bought a new S.D card that is a Lexar 16gb for my Pi-3 with 7" touchscreen. I transferred the information from the original SD to this one, only replacing the Rasbian Jesse. I load it up and I get a "Kernel panic" but I noticed that the numbers at the end are different from everyones. Its "179,7". I had only loaded "Boot" and not "Recovery". But when I had them in the same file, The Pi would not reconize the SD. Is there a better way to stock the SD or to fix the Kernel Error?

Comment: the old card is still working? what means replacing jesse?

Comment: How would you "transfer the infromation from the original SD to the new card"? +I would suggest you to use the [piclone utility](https://github.com/raspberrypi/piclone) to do this.

Comment: This question is no more clear than the last one I closed from your other username.  Rather than following the advice given you there, you have simply decided to ignore it.  For that reason I am deleting this account.  If you want help, listen.  If you do not, don't ask.